What Windows API allow to block keyboard input to another application?
My application working with special hardware device what inject keyboard characters as input from keyboard to active window. That device look as barcode scanner and connected to computer with USB port.
In some condition my application need to change keyboard stream (for example change 'FB' to 'FE' characters and in some condition I need to clear keyboard buffer and full block entering characters stream at all. Usually this happens when device producing double keyboard stream.
Currently device mostly used with Excel, but next generation of this application will be used with another accounting program.
I made keylogger based on SetWindowsHookEx and have in my program all condition when I need to change keyboard input and when I need to block keyboard stream to Excel.
Currently this is console application with my special application logic:

I can change it to Windows Forms application and select in my apps another active window what will accept distorted input from my device (currently Excel but in next generation will used another application).
Unfortunately I don't understand how in my program I can block input to Excel and how I can clear all stream what generate virtual keyboard (in fact my device).
What windows API I need to use to lock entering characters to Active window (currently Excel)? How to clear all characters in keyboard stream?
Security problem not applicable, my application will working with Windows administrator account.

You can prevent keyboard input from reaching a window by calling EnableWindow. You cannot purge keyboard input messages that have already entered the message queue from a different thread. Though, this all reads like you are trying to avoid solving the actual problem.

thanks, will try experiment with this API, actual problem in hardware layer, device don't working full correctly, create a lot of doubles for example. But thanks, will try to use this API, thanks
